# how to choose a chosen quantity and random order from a dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop, range

how to get only a certain number of question and not all? and randomly, i tried but im stuck

```
import random
score = 0
questions = [
 { 'question': "first question",
 'answer': ["dea", "hay"] },
 { 'question': "second question",
 'answer': ["deo", "hoy"] },
 { 'question': "third question",
 'answer': ["dei", "hey"] }, 
]

for j in questions: preguntas = j.get("question") print(preguntas)
respuesta = input("respuesta: ")
correcta = j.get("answer")

if respuesta in correcta:
    score += 1
print("your score is", score)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
for j in questions: preguntas = j.get("question") print(preguntas)
```

try

```
N = 2  # your target number of questions
for j in random.choices(questions, k = N): preguntas = j.get("question") print(preguntas)
```